# kernel_require.rb file cannot load such file but I have the gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, gemfile

I get the output:

> /Users/JZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- HTTPClient (LoadError)

I have run `gem install httpclient` and `bundle install` and it says that all gems have been installed.

I have multiple ruby versions, could this be the issue?

Running `which -a ruby` returns:

```
/Users/JZ/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I have seen that others have had this issue and it fixed it for them, but I think I have the right version of ruby.

I have tried just about everything, from uninstalling Ruby / Rails to uninstalling bundler, but don't know how to fix this!

Here's the full trace:

```
4: from bin/rails:5:in `<main>'
3: from /Users/JZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
2: from /Users/JZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
1: from /Users/JZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
/Users/JZ/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require': cannot load such file -- HTTPClient (LoadError)
```

Comment: Could you add full backtrace? It is need to know what happened before loading HTTPClient.

Comment: i posted the full trace!

Comment: Can you add your inputs of `bootsnap` Gemfile, boot.rb, etc.? Remove `require 'bootsnap/setup'` from your `boot.rb` file

Comment: having a similar issue! its driving me nuts